# Binding ObservableCollection<Foo> to ObservableCollection<object>

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding, observablecollection

I have a collection `ObservableCollection<Foo>`, and I want to bind this to a property in a custom controller of type `ObservableCollection<object>`. However, the bound value never reaches the PropertyCallback, and is hence never set.

Is there a clever way to achieve this binding? I could create an IValueConverter that converts from `ObservableCollection<Foo>` to `ObservableCollection<object>`, but [that gives new problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675922/howto-observe-converted-collections)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no automatic conversion. Writing a ValueConverter is an option.

If you have often the need for this specific conversion, maybe a [TypeConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter(VS.80).aspx) can do what you need. After creating, declare it with the [TypeConverterAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverterattribute(v=VS.80).aspx), then in bindings automatic conversion will be done.

Comment: TypeConverter might be better, but I guess that gives the same problems IValueConverter do? (See referenced question in edit).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a beautiful way of achieving this. You might want to look into Covariance and Contravariance (.Net 4), but it won't work for your object example.