# Howto observe converted collections?

Tags: .net, wpf, ivalueconverter

I bind a collection `ObservableCollection<Foo>` to a dependency property on my controller, but I run it through an IValueConverter to make it `ObservableCollection<object>` instead, which is what my controller expect. The conversion works fine - I create an `ObservableCollection<object>` and fill it with all the Foo's from the original list. This however brings a problem which is that now I'm observing on the collection created in the value converter, and hence doesn't see any of the changes to the original collection.

So; do I have to hook up eventhandlers in the converter to manually keep the converted collection in sync with the original one, or is there a better way to handle this? I guess I can't do the convertion without actually creating a new collection? Or can I do the binding in some clever way such that I don't have to do the convert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it helps, but often in a ViewModel, I declare `IList` or another less specific interface as the property type instead of a specific one.

Then I can bind quasi all collections and lists to this propery.

While the property is set, I check if it Implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and if yes, I attach an CollectionChanged-EventHandler.  When the property has changed newly, I remove the EventHandler from the old `INotifyPropertyChanged` (if it was).

The drawback of this is, that the ViewModel must be prepared to see objects other types than expected. But this is normally a simple job.

```
void YourDPValueChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
    INotifyCollectionChanged newCollection = e.NewValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;
    INotifyCollectionChanged oldCollection = e.OldValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;
    if (null != newCollection) {
        newCollection.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(Collection_CollectionChanged);
    }
    if (null != oldCollection) {
        oldCollection.CollectionChanged -= new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(Collection_CollectionChanged);
    }
```

Comment: Thx for your attention. I tried that, but it doesn't seem to help me. I normally use IList too, but I believe the problem is the type of objects the list holds. I hoped that a list of object can have a list of anything bound to it, but the dependency property is only triggered if I bind a collection of the exact same type to it - also when using IList..

Comment: @stiank81: This looks as it is a problem with the Binding: ObservableCollection<T> implements Collection<T> and this implements IList. Therefore it can not be a problem of the contained type. Do I understand the initial design right: Your ViewModel has this IList-property and you bind from your View an ObservableCollection<T> to it. Right?

Comment: My ViewModel has an ObservableCollection<Foo>, and in my view I have a control with property ObservableCollection<object> which I bind the ObservableCollection<Foo> to. The binding isn't applied due to the type mismatch, and it seems like I have to change one of them to get a match in the binding. That's what I tried solving using an IValueConverter, but then I get an extra collection in between which means I loose track of the original ObservableCollection in me ViewModel.

Comment: @stiank81: Ok, in this case, if you don't want to change the ViewModel's property to a IList or IEnumerable, I think you have to write a converter that makes the conversion and also connects the source-and the destination-collection for CollectionChanged-events. Another idea could be to add a second property in your ViewModel that has the same purpose as the specific one but supports IList? This makes the VM a little bit more complex but then you have both options, a strongly typed and a generic one.

Comment: Yeah, seems like this will be the solution.. Have considered adding a generic list to my ViewModel, but I don't think I'd like to do that.. Thanks for your input on this!

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you are binding some sort of ICollection that does not implement INotifyCollectionChanged through a converter that creates a new ObservableCollection. In that case you would not get any benefit from the now disconnected collection.
Is it possible to bind your collection directly (without converting) and implementing INotifyPropertyChanged and/or INotifyCollectionChanged directly on your object?

Comment: I'm sorry if the question was unclear - some parts of the code wasn't showing, but I added code blocks now. I am binding An ObservableCollection to an ObservableCollection-property. The problem is the type of elements, which is why I have to add a converter (or is there a better way?). In the converter a new collection is created, making me loose the observing of the original one. The question is how to best keep observing the original one. Can I add a more clever binding? Or do I need to keep them in sync manually.